# Eloquent make the query return null when related table found nothing

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I am currently new in Eloquent and I am facing a problem here, I dont know the right terminologies when it comes to this, but currently this is my query

```
    $mentor = $this->user->where("Role", "Mentor")->with(['article' => function ($query) use ($q) {
        $query->where("cat_id", $q);
    }])->get();
```

Yes, it works but thats not exactly the output I need, the article table returns empty as expected but I would like to the query to return empty when no article is found. How can I do that? This still returns data even when the article is null. Is what I wanted possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mentor = $this->user->with('article')->where("Role", "Mentor")->whereHas('article', function ($query) use ($q) {
        $query->where("cat_id", $q);
    })->get();
```